# ASP.NET MVC3 - Restrict Bundle Config Code from user

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have registered bundles using below code in Global.asax.cs file. When I enter domain name with bundles path in browser, I am able to view js content in browser. Below URL should not display any content in the browser.

At least I would like to restrict user access to url if it has bundles. Is it possible to restrict bundles only to user and not to browser?

https://myworld.com/home/bundles/jqueryval

https://myworld.com/home/bundles/globalization

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    .Include("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")
    .Include("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/globalization")
    .Include("~/Scripts/globalize/globalize.js")
    .Include("~/Scripts/globalize/cultures/globalize.culture.es-CL.js")
    .Include("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.globalize.js"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your bundles are JavaScript and CSS files. It should be public and accessible so that the browser can download and execute them. And you cannot disable them from user being viewed. It can be minified but you can't hide them from user.

You can enable or disable using below code. If you disable then browser also cannot access it.

```
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true; 
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false;
```